# Are country-specific questions too localized?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

Are the country specific situation too localized?

On my question [EU-citizen working as contractor in Switzerland?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/93/eu-citizen-working-as-contractor-in-switzerland) one user have said

> it is only relevant to a small geographic area

If it would be only one user, I would simply ignore him, but there are more close votes. So this is no longer funny, but very dangerous to the very concept of the site.

If the country-specific questions are not allowed, it means that no questions about working as contractor and any issues with it (is it necessary to register company, what taxes one must pay etc., what are the typical pro-hour wages) will be excluded from the site.

This means that it would be something like **Workplace for Freelancers**, or could be as well renamed to **Work@Home**. It would be simple not the site I was committed to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think country-specific situations are too localized unless they have no hope of helping anyone but the question asker. Currently, your question has 4 close votes on it, likely due to a user's comment.

The scope of your question applies to what I would argue would be fine for this site; it applies to other people (namely EU citizens working in Switzerland, which is actually a very popular topic due to its relations with the EU)

If your question *is* closed, I would vote to re-open it. Don't be put off; we are just in the first day of beta, and building what we accept as a community.

Answer (score 8):

No, please, **this is not at all what is meant by "too localized."** There's nothing about the practice of an entire country/state/city/community that would be considered "too localized."

This close reason is being severely reworked because of these misunderstandings (more on that soon) — but it almost [never makes sense to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87416/98786) because it pertains to a specific country.

Comment: The honda civic reference made me chuckle. I think many of the users here are jumping on a bandwagon about things being "localized" without realizing what it really means.

Comment: With regard to the laws of one country/state/city/community, if one takes the "too localized" thought process mentioned by @ŁukaszLech to its logical conclusion, then nobody can ask a legal question here. Almost everyone lives in only one (not multiple) country/state/city/community. Switzerland is home to around 8 million people. Massachusetts is home to almost 7 million people. Yet my question on the ideal business entity in MA was also closed as "too localized." I'm not annoyed by it, but it's funny that my RI question (home to only about 1 million people) has not yet also been closed.

Comment: @CopyrightX the last vote is the binding vote that specifies close reason, and i think a few of your close votes were for "off topic".